# data type to use in mysql for timezones

Tags: mysql, timezone

I store a date/time in my database that is UTC.  I'm working to add conversion of this once a user selects a timezone so it shows local time for them.  Basically the user selects from a form:

```
<select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone">
   <option value="-12.0">(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>
   <option value="-11.0">(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
   <option value="-10.0">(GMT -10:00) Hawaii</option>
   ...
```

I can make the option value anything I want but an easy to remember one is as above. What data type would I use for mysql?  Does it really matter in this case?  Would TINYINT do?  Maybe using an ENUM would be a good idea?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scheme you're proposing (storing time zones as an integer offset from GMT) may fail for the following cases:

- India, which is on UTC + 05:30 (not an integer number of hours).
- Kiribati, which is on UTC + 14:00 (over 12 hours).
- Distinguishing British Time and GMT. (The former uses Daylight Saving Time; the latter is not.)
- Distinguishing between some pairs of countries which use the same GMT offset, but which switch at different times of the year.

For full time zone support, I'd recommend using the [`zoneinfo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) database and storing time zones as strings (e.g, "America/New_York").

Comment: This seems daunting. This is a list of 405 timezones. I understand this is important for DST but presenting a user a select option with 405 entries seems unusable. Is that what everyone is doing or are people presenting a shorter list and forgetting about DST?

Comment: At a minimum, I'd recommend picking and choosing some common time zones from the zoneinfo database. That'll at least make sure DST works properly for those zones.

Comment: @Tom: Don't give them a list of 405 timezones, use the America/New_York form, ask them to name the nearest major city, and include an auto-completer. And you can't just ignore DST: Arizona and Utah are in the same timezone, UT uses DST but AZ does not.

Comment: Thx, I think that is what I have, I'll stick to my short list which I'll cross reference with zoneinfo.  I guess VARCHAR will be used to store the value.

Comment: @muistooshort thx, I'll take a look, hopefully something like this is already done with jquery or something.

Comment: Check out the Chosen plugin for jQuery - it gives you a sweet searchable autocompleting <select>: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

Although this is very old. But for anybody still looking for the solution. I used
date-fns with time zones. I am using reactjs with node.js . Only had to add one extra column to the table - and always store time in UTC format only - and the corresponding zone in the additional column.

https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/Time-Zones

```
import { zonedTimeToUtc } from 'date-fns-tz'

const date = getDatePickerValue() // e.g. 2014-06-25 10:00:00 (picked in any time zone)
const timeZone = getTimeZoneValue() // e.g. America/Los_Angeles

const utcDate = zonedTimeToUtc(date, timeZone) // In June 10am in Los Angeles is 5pm UTC

postToServer(utcDate.toISOString(), timeZone) // post 2014-06-25T17:00:00.000Z, America/Los_Angeles
```

And for the scenario of timezones - list. https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-and-timezones